# How can I check if buffer has been modified even after save-buffer

Tags: hooks

I need to test if the buffer has been modified even if `(save-buffer)` has been called after the changes.

I thought to use `add-variable-watcher` but I found that `buffer-modified-p` is a function, not a variable.

I thought something like `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'myfunction)` where `myfunction` should set a `custom-variable` on `t` and remove the hook at the same time. In this case I could test `(or (buffer-modified-p) custom-variable)`

I mean something like

```el
(defun myfunction (VAR)
  (setq VAR t)
  (remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'myfunction)

(defmacro mymacro
   `(let ((VAR nil))

      (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'myfunction)

      ,@body

      (if (or (buffer-modified-p) VAR) ...)))
```

(This is not a MWE but only an idea of code...)

How can I add a function with one argument (`custom-variable`) to 'before-save-hook? Is it a bad idea? I need to avoid `lambda` function because of the need to remove it from the hook.

I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: Please clarify.  You talk about variable watchers as if you were wanting to react to changes *when they happen*, but then also talk about `before-save-hook` as if you're not concerned about changes unless you're about to save the buffer to a file.  What is it that you want to do?  Describe the behaviour you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You could use `write-region` instead of `save-buffer`, if that is an option for you. It would 'save' your buffer without setting it 'unmodified'.

Comment: @phils the reaction to the changes would be setting `VAR` on `t`. I'm just looking for a way to check if the buffer has been modified at the end of ,@body even if user (interactively) or functions saved the buffer.

Comment: @dalanicolai `write-region` is not an option, thanks.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi You call `(buffer-modified-p)` to check if the buffer has been modified.  But I believe you *already* know that, and knew before you asked the question, so I *still* don't understand what the question is, or how hooks or variable watchers come into it.

Comment: @phils at the end of `body` the buffer could have been modified by user/function but if user/function saved the buffer with `(save-buffer)`, `(buffer-modified-p)` would be useless for my purpose.

Comment: Especially confusing is that your first sentence talks about *after* `save-buffer` but you go on to do things with `before-save-hook` rather than `after-save-hook`.

Comment: Are you just wanting `(let ((VAR (buffer-modified-p))) ...)`??

Comment: @phils you're right, sorry for my poor english. I edited the issue.

Comment: @phils I just figured out that I could let-bind `before-save-hook` and use a `lambda` function... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```el
(let ((modified (buffer-modified-p)))
  ...do things...
  (when modified
    ...do more things...))
```